# LCM of $19+x$ and $51+x$ is $420$ what is the value of $x$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

If I take $(19+x) = y$ then $(51+x) = y+ 32$ , using this I can cancel a factor of $4$ but I can't solve it any further.

Comment: Hint:  lcm$(a,b)=\frac {ab}{\gcd(a,b)}$.

Comment: How do I find the GCD of these two values?

Comment: Well, you can't find it instantly, but if $d$ divides both $y$ and $y+32$ then it must divide $32$.

Comment: Could you please explain how to solve this problem . I am really confused.

Comment: I'll post something below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We will use the form $y, y+32$ as proposed in the question.

We know that $$\text {lcm}(a,b)=\frac {ab}{\gcd (a,b)}$$

It is clear that $d=\gcd(y,y+32)$ must be a divisor of $32$.  Hence $d\in \{1,2,2^2,2^3,2^4,2^5\}$.

We will proceed case by case.

I.  $d=1$ then we solve $y(y+32)=420\implies y=\{-42,10\}$.  However neither of these are relatively prime to $32$ so No Solution.

II. $d=2$ then we solve $y(y+32)=2\times 420$ which has no integer solutions, so No Solution.

III. $d=4$ then we solve $y(y+32)=4\times 420\implies y=\{-60,28\}$  Both of these work since $\gcd (-60,32)=4=\gcd(28,32)$. (Though perhaps the OP intended to assume $y>0$).  Easy to see that this gives us the solutions $$\boxed {x=\{-79,9\}}$$

IV.  $d=8$ then we solve $y(y+32)=8\times 420$ which has no integer solutions, so No Solution.

V. $d=16$ then we solve $y(y+32)=16\times 420$ which has no integer solutions, so No Solution.

VI $d=32$ then we solve $y(y+32)=32\times 420$ which has no integer solutions, so No Solution.

Thus the only solutions are $$\boxed {x=\{-79,9\}}$$

Comment: Thanks it's really helpful. So we have to check all the cases , isn't there any direct method?

Comment: Of course there might be, but the lcm makes that difficult.  whatever formula you tried to write out would need to take the gcd into account and that seems like a case by case thing to me.  Note my first case, for instance, in which we found likely solutions but rejected them because of the gcd.

Comment: Thanks again. I was stuck for quite some time.

Comment: The last three cases can be easily dismissed since $420$ is divisible by $4$ but not by $8$.

Answer (score 3):

Given $a:=x+19, b:=x+51$, we can see $b-a=32$ and thus $\gcd(a,b)\mid 32$ (and is thus a power of $2$).

Since ${\rm lcm}(a,b)=420$, we can also say $\gcd(a,b)\mid 420$ and thus $\gcd(a,b) = 4$, since the difference of $32$ means that $(4 \mid a)\iff (4\mid b)$.

Thus $ab = 420\cdot 4 = 1680$. Then, solving for positive integers, we need a pair of numbers divisble by $4$ but not $8$, difference $32$ and (by inspection) $a<40<b$, with $40{-}a<b{-}40$. The options then are $a\in \{28,36\}$ and the first works, $(a,b)=(28,60)$ and $x=9$.

$(a,b) = (-60,-28)$ and $x=-79$ is also valid if negative solutions are permitted.